# Java NewLine "\n" not working in save to text file

Tags: java, file-io

Here is my code:

```
public String display() {
    return "\n......................\nFixed Employee:\n" + 
           "Name: " + super.fullName() + 
           "\nSalary: " + salary() + 
           " tk\n......................";
}
```

But when I'm invoking this method from main class, "\n" newLine not working. just showing one line output. Will you plz help to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the string displayed? On console? Or in a control?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, I am saving this "display" in txt file.

Comment: The way you have written it suggests you think that `\n` behave different in `return` statements which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For saving in files use `\r\n`. `\n` as new lines is viable on printstreams but not writing to files.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe its working. Thanks. I am using FileWriter and BufferedWriter.

Comment: -1 There is no base for this answer. Since when is `\n` exclusive to printing?

Comment: \r does the trick when writing text files!!!

Answer (score 2):

You may need the system independent line separator as it might differ from one OS to another. Just replace the **\n** with the value of line separator:

- I can be retrieve as you load any system property:

```java
    public String display() { 
      String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // Load the system property using its key.
      return "\n......................\nFixed Employee:\n" 
        + "Name: " 
        + super.fullName() + 
        "\nSalary: " 
        + salary() 
        + " tk\n......................"
      .replace("\\n", separator); // replace the \n before returning your String 
    }
```

- Or simply use `System#lineSeparator` method as @Deepanshu Bedi suggested:

```java
    public String display() { 
      String separator = System.lineSeparator(); // Consider it as a shortcut.
      return "\n......................\nFixed Employee:\n" 
        + "Name: " 
        + super.fullName() + 
        "\nSalary: " 
        + salary() 
        + " tk\n......................"
      .replace("\\n", separator); // replace the \n before returning your String 
}
```

Comment: +1 for use of `System.lineSeperator()`, though for this case using standard `\r\n` may work as fine for `.txt` files. The use of `.replace()` is also going to slow down the operation (due to regex) use `+ separator` in concatenation instead so compiler can optimize it.

Comment: Yes absolutely right, though using `System.lineSeperator()` save independent machine code and deliver mor code visibitity.